# Unix - How do you pass / pipe the output of a sed command to a ls command in Unix

Tags: unix, sed, ls

I am able to determine the size of an input file using the following command :

```
ls -l employee.txt | awk '{print $5}'
```

This will print only the file size.

And I am able to print the contents of a file ignoring first and last line (refers to header & trailer) of the file. Below command does this work for me :

```
sed '1d;$d' employee.txt
```

But how to combine both these commands in such a way that it should determine the size of the file ignoring header and trailer. At the same time the header and trailer should not be removed from the input file.

I am able to achieve this by writing two statements. One to copy the full file into a new file except header and trailer and then doing a ls on the new file as below :

```
sed '1d;$d' employee.txt > employee1.txt

ls -l employee1.txt
```

I tried to do it in a single statement as below but to no avail. Any inputs will be helpful.

```
sed '1d;$d' employee.txt | ls -l employee.txt

ls -l `sed '1d;$d' employee.txt`

sed '1d;$d' employee.txt |xargs ls -l $1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) to get the file size. To get the size of a file on disk, use `stat -c '%s' filename`, or to get the size of a stream of characters, use `wc -c`.

```
# size of employee.txt
stat -c '%s' employee.txt

# size without header and footer
sed '1d;$d' employee.txt | wc -c
```

Comment: sed option with wc looks much better. If you don't mind, can you just explain in detail what would be the difference between stat -c and wc -c in general ?

Comment: stat only works with files. wc can work with files or with reading text from stding (i.e. when it's on the right-hand side of a pipe)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through

```
cat someFilename.txt | wc -c
```

The first command outputs the content of the file and the second one counts the size of the input.

This does not remove the header and the trailer. For that you can use 'sed' command as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're approaching this in the wrong way.

My suggestion: query the total file size using the "stat" command:

```
stat --format=%s employee.txt
```

You can store the result in a variable like this (assuming you're running a Bash shell):

```
fileSize="$(stat --format=%s employee.txt)"
```

Now you retrieve the first line (assuming Bash shell again):

```
firstLine="$(head -n 1 employee.txt)"
```

Next you retrieve the last line (assuming Bash shell again):

```
lastLine="$(tail -n 1 employee.txt)"
```

Now compute the size of the first and the last line and subtract it from the file size:

```
echo "Total adjusted size is:" $((fileSize - ${#firstLine} - ${#lastLine}))
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JScottMiller but I am afraid no one will use this option

Comment: @JKC, please elaborate, are you going to use it in a script or is it just for one-time use? In the former case I'd highly recommend to use my suggestion in the later case, other versions might be more appropriate, if you're not used to programming.

Comment: I am going to use it in the script only and your option is too long and not much helpful. We can achieve this with just a single liner or two.

Comment: @JKC, keep in mind that the "wc" solution counts all the characters in the file, while a stat-based solution simply queries this information from the filesystem.

Comment: Yes @JScottMiller . So why should I do these many stat statements when I can achieve my requirement with just single statement ? Please let me know how your answer is more efficient than glen jackman's answer - sed '1d;$d' employee.txt | wc -c